# Worksheet_Change Sub slow autocalculation

Tags: vba, events, worksheet, changelog, datestamp

I have a very complex Excel file that should have been replaced with a database a looong time ago, however it is not possible at the time. There is a need to implement a way to record when a change was made to a certain columns and record the date when the change was made.

I wrote the following script:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim VRange As Range, cell As Range
Dim Vrange2 As Range, cell2 As Range
Dim Vrange3 As Range, Cell3 As Range
Dim Vrange4 As Range, Cell4 As Range
Dim Vrange5 As Range, Cell5 As Range
Dim Vrange6 As Range, Cell6 As Range

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set VRange = Range("J5:J7000")
For Each cell In Target
If Union(cell, VRange).Address = VRange.Address Then
cell.Offset(, 8) = "TS on " & Date
End If
Next cell

Set Vrange2 = Range("K5:K7000")
For Each cell2 In Target
If Union(cell2, Vrange2).Address = Vrange2.Address Then
cell2.Offset(, 7) = "GS on " & Date
End If
Next cell2

Set Vrange3 = Range("M5:M7000")
For Each Cell3 In Target
If Union(Cell3, Vrange3).Address = Vrange3.Address Then
Cell3.Offset(, 5) = "P on " & Date
End If
Next Cell3

Set Vrange4 = Range("O5:O7000")
For Each Cell4 In Target
If Union(Cell4, Vrange4).Address = Vrange4.Address Then
Cell4.Offset(, 3) = "GD on " & Date
End If
Next Cell4

Set Vrange5 = Range("P5:P7000")
For Each Cell5 In Target
If Union(Cell5, Vrange5).Address = Vrange5.Address Then
Cell5.Offset(, 2) = "TD on " & Date
End If
Next Cell5

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'doesnt do anything
End Sub
```

It works as a clockwork, however due to the nature of the spreadsheet it takes forever to recalculate if more than one cells were changed (since it recalculates after the cell is changed, then runs the macro, which changes another cell, so it recalculates again and it repeats the process for every single cell that was changed) The calculation time of 1,5 seconds becomes unbearable when you change over 50 cells.

Inserting `Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual` didnt help, since I need it to be automatic after the macro finished running, so I have to put `Application.Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic` in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with `Worksheet_Change` events together with `Calculation` mode changes, always use this:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

When all cells are changed, use the opposite to enable it again:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```